# The Asp.Net Core v3.1 does not work on last win iot v17763 and Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: asp.net-core, raspberry-pi

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create from template (default) Asp.Net Core Web Application (Model-View-Controller) project with disable "Configure for HTTPS" in VS2019 v16.4.2
2. Set up "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000" in launchSettings.json
3. Create deployment for raspberry pi: `dotnet publish -r win-arm`
4. Copy directory to raspberry pi.
5. Open port 5000
6. Start server 'WebApplication1' on raspberry pi
7. The WebApplication1.exe is in run process list, but no access to Web server. The desktop version of WebApplication1 works without problems.

Comment: No experience myself, but maybe some of this could help: https://thomaslevesque.com/2018/04/17/hosting-an-asp-net-core-2-application-on-a-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Thank you for help. Asp.Net Core 3.1 works on Raspberry win10 iot too. I forgot add this: webBuilder.UseUrls("http://*:5000");